# Modal topmost WPF Window called by .ShowDialog is shown in background

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application in which I want to password protect a tabitem in my central tabcontrol.

So I am using the tabControl_SelectionChanged event in my MainWindow.xaml.cs in which I call a modal password dialog if the selected tabitem has a tag = "password".

```
private void tabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TabItem selectedItem = (TabItem)e.AddedItems[0];

        if (selectedItem.Tag != null && selectedItem.Tag.Equals("Password"))
        {
            PasswordView pw = new PasswordView();
            pw.Owner = this;
            bool? result = pw.ShowDialog();

            if (result.HasValue && !result.Value)
            {
                tabControl.SelectedItem = tabControl.Items[0];
            }
        }
    }
```

Here the properties of the password dialog:

```
Topmost="True"  
Title="PasswordView"      
WindowStyle="None" 
ResizeMode="NoResize" 
WindowState="Maximized"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
ShowInTaskbar="False"
```

Properties of MainWindow:

```
WindowState="Maximized" 
WindowStyle="None" 
ResizeMode="NoResize"
```

The view shows a textbox and a button. On button click I am checking the password in the viewmodel and send a MVVMLight message to the password view, so the view can set the DialogResult and closes it self. (I have done it also with the DialogCloser with databinding the DialogResult and I got the same result)

In the viewmodel:

```
if (password.Equals(Properties.Settings.Default.ServicePassword))
        {
            PasswordOk = true;
        }
        else
        {
            PasswordOk = false;
        }

        password = "";

        Messenger.Default.Send<NotificationMessage>(
            new NotificationMessage(this, "CloseWindowsBoundToMe")
        );
```

and the view:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, (nm) => CloseWindow(nm));


    private void CloseWindow(NotificationMessage nm)
    {
        if (nm.Notification == "CloseWindowsBoundToMe")
        {
            if (nm.Sender == this.DataContext)
            {
                PasswordViewModel pvm = ((PasswordViewModel)DataContext);
                DialogResult = pvm.PasswordOk;
            }
        }
    }
```

Back in the MainWindow.xaml.cs I am checking the DialogResult. If true (password is ok) nothing is done and if false I set the SelectedItem of the tabcontrol to the main tab.

```
TabItem selectedItem = (TabItem)e.AddedItems[0];

        if (selectedItem.Tag != null && selectedItem.Tag.Equals("Password"))
        {
            PasswordView pw = new PasswordView();
            pw.Owner = this;
            bool? result = pw.ShowDialog();

            if (result.HasValue && !result.Value)
            {
                tabControl.SelectedItem = tabControl.Items[0];
            }
        }
```

Basically all is working fine, but if I want to change in the protected tabitem more than 3 times with entering a wrong password the modal password view did not show in foreground. Only Alt+Tab brings the dialog to foreground....

This result is reproducible -> trying 3 times is ok then the next try the password dialog is shown in background.

There is another password protected tab, if I click this tab after the password dialog gets stuck in background two password dialogs are shown...

So the question is: Why is the modal password dialog not working always the same?

---

Comment: Remove that Tompost flag - you don't need it if you show modal window. It often causes weird issues with windowing model.

Comment: Thank you - I added this propery in my dispair. So setting the TopMost to true or false has no effect on my problem.

Comment: ... Removing also does not the trick

Comment: I believe this is just a peculiarity of the selection change notification handling which is potentially confused by the additional nested events caused by the modal window being shown and/or the selected tab being changed during processing of the original selection change event.  Try and alter the flow so that the dialog is not called directly from the SelectionChanged event handler.

Comment: e.g. you could perhaps consider allowing the user to select the protected tab but just display alternative "You must be logged in to view" content if they are not yet authorised, and then pop up the password dialog modal outside of the selection change notification event, for example using Task.Run(() => {Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {ShowPasswordDialog();}))}); to show the dialog once current events have been processed.

Comment: Thank you - I will try a workaround like this if nobody comes up with a better solution.

Comment: There are sometimes weird issues if you are hitting breakpoints in the code using `ShowDialog` while debugging in Visual Studio. Check that this issue appears in standalone application.

Comment: Standalone applications (debug and release version) are showing the same result. If I set a breakpoint before opening the password dialog the dialog stays in foreground (because i have to switch between my application and VisualStudio - I suppose)....Nevertheless thanks